# Organising code for Tkinter Two-Player Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, button, tkinter

I'm trying to make a two-player game where people take it in turns to make a move. I feel like I have to manually change the master window in order for the two to have the same content and widgets. How do I make things simpler for myself? How do I make switching between the two windows easier?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Game')
    
def win1():
    global board
    top2.withdraw()
    top1.deiconify()
    board=top1

def win2():
    top1.withdraw()
    top2.deiconify()
    board=top2
    
top1 = Toplevel()
board = top1
top1.title('Player 1')
top1.withdraw()
buttonp1 = Button(top1, text="Switch to Player 2", command=win2)
buttonp1.grid(row=15, column=0, columnspan=10)


top2 = Toplevel()
board = top2
top2.title('Player 2')
top2.withdraw()
buttonp2 = Button(top2,text="Switch to Player 1", command=win1)
buttonp2.grid(row=15, column=0, columnspan=10)

choice = Button(text="Submit Weapons Choices", command=win1)
choice.grid()
#After this button is pressed, win1 is opened, and the switching from window to window begins.

top_array = [top1, top2]

# When generating the board, I would use "for top in top_array", then run a function which generates widgets. I want the board to start off with the exact same layout.
```

Problems that I run into involve not being able to change text variables later on in the code, because it was generated in a function:

```
top_array = [top1, top2]

def init(board):
    txt = StringVar(board)
    txt.set("\nClick anywhere to begin\n")
    label = Label(board, textvariable=txt)
    label.grid(row = 11, column = 0, columnspan=10)
    
for top in top_array:
    init(top)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a class to make both windows start off with the same content, but have different titles, etc. and an array so that I could switch between the two

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, board, tag, name):
        self.board = board
        self.tag = tag
        self.name = name

p = Player(root,"","")
board1 = Toplevel()
board2 = Toplevel()
gamemode = [Player(board1, "Switch to Player 2", "Player 1"), Player(board2, "Switch to Player 1", "Player 2")]

def switch():
    global pnum
    pnum +=1
    pnum %= 2
    gamemode[pnum].board.withdraw()
    gamemode[((pnum+1)%2)].board.deiconify()
```